# packing rectangles into a container rectangle with minimum overlap

Tags: algorithm, packing

I have a case where I have a container rectangle of fixed dimensions, say WXH and I want to fill it up with two kinds of rectangles, with dimensions say w1Xh1 and w2Xh2,we can assume that w1,w2,h1 and h2 are integers, and these filling rectangles can be rotated by 90 degrees only. I want to fill up the container rectangle completely, for which there will be overlaps between rectangles. So, I have two objectives, first to determine minimum overlap area possible, and second determining the tiling placement(s) of rectangles that results in this minimum overlap area. How do I approach this problem? Is it possible to derive an exact solution algo for this? Will there be a unique tile placement solution?

Comment: Start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem#Packing_rectangles

Comment: "Will there be a unique tile placement solution?" No.  For example, consider W=7, H=1, w1=5, h1=1, w2=3, h1=1.

Comment: in the above case, a tile placement solution with minimum overlap will be placing the two tiles with an overlap area of 1 sq units, I cannot think of any other possible solution with an overlap area of 1

Comment: In the @mbeckish example (and also in the no-overlap example W=7, H=1, w1=5, h1=1, w2=2, h1=1) there are two solutions hence no unique solution.  But if you exclude mirrored or rotated copies of a solution, both examples have unique solutions.

Comment: @Bitwise i went through the wikipedia article, but it doesn't really describe an algorithm for the same